# Creating multiple buttons with modal dialogs in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following Shiny Application:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

UI <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    column(10,
           plotOutput("line_graph")),
    #Pop up windows, for three buttons on the left side
    bsModal("modalExample1", "Your plot", "a_plot", size = "large",
            plotOutput("plot1"), downloadButton('downloadPlot', 'Download')),
    #bsModal("modalExample2", "Your plot", "b_plot", size = "large",
    #        plotOutput("plot2"), downloadButton('downloadPlot', 'Download')),



    column(2,
           actionButton("a_plot","Bubble chart"),
           actionButton("b_plot","Graph view"))
  )
))

Server <- function(input, output) {

  output$line_graph <- renderPlot({hist(10)})
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({hist(20)})
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({hist(30)})



}
shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```

When I press the button "a_plot" you'll get a pop up windows with a graph. This works. However I would also like to accomplish that I get another graph popping up when I press "b_plot".

However when I uncomment the this code:

It does not work. Any feedback on how I get this working?

```
#bsModal("modalExample2", "Your plot", "b_plot", size = "large",
#        plotOutput("plot2"), downloadButton('downloadPlot', 'Download')),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 elements with the `id` = `downloadPlot` you cannot have that, you need to have unique `id` always

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

UI <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    column(10,
           plotOutput("line_graph")),
    #Pop up windows, for three buttons on the left side
    bsModal("modalExample1", "Your plot", "a_plot", size = "large",
            plotOutput("plot1"), downloadButton('downloadPlot', 'Download')),
    bsModal("modalExample2", "Your plot", "b_plot", size = "large",
           plotOutput("plot2"), downloadButton('downloadPlot2', 'Download')),

    column(2,
           actionButton("a_plot","Bubble chart"),
           actionButton("b_plot","Graph view"))
  )
))

Server <- function(input, output) {

  output$line_graph <- renderPlot({hist(10)})
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({hist(20)})
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({hist(30)})

}

shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```